Biaxial Strain under Quantum Espresso
for a strain effect on 3D cubic materials, when studying the unstrained structure, its properties then applying the strain pourcentage in order to compare, changing the a and b values and keeping the c value, then a vc-relax is performed with a cell_dofree for 'z', is this the correct approach ? the vc-relax gives a change to c value which is normal but when comparing the band gap value of the strained and unstrained structure, it isn't a good result since with a compressive strain the band gap's value decreases but in this case it increases with a 1eV difference.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sorry for confusing, asking about how to approach the structure optimization(relax or vc-relax) after applying Biaxial Strain on a 3D cubic crystal structure in order to go on with the electronic properties calculations and get the right results ?
